# Using Clojure tools.cli, how do I validate that only acceptable options were passed?

Tags: clojure

My CLI tool has options, for example  `-a` `-b` and `-c`.

If a user passes `-d`, I want to fail with an error message. Of course I could code up an ad-hoc check, but how do I do this with [tools.cli](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors are communicated in the result of `parse-opts`.  This means, it's
your responsibility to actually fail in the case, you don't accept
arbitrary arguments.

E.g.

```clj
(require '[clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])

(def cli-options
  [["-a" "--aye" "A"]
   ["-b" "--bee" "B"]])

(parse-opts *command-line-args* cli-options)
```

Running with (for the sake of brevity, I use babashka, formatting is
mine):

```
% bb x.bb -a -b -d
{:options {:aye true, 
           :bee true}, 
 :arguments [], 
 :summary "  -a, --aye  A\n  -b, --bee  B", 
 :errors ["Unknown option: \"-d\""]}
```

As you can see, there is a key `:errors` and it points to a vector of
strings with all the errors.

If you need inspiration for how to deal with the common case of writing
a "main" function, that behaves properly (e.g. show the usage, fail on
error...) I suggest a peek at the ["Example Usage" section of
tools.cli](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli#example-usage)